# Compilation needed for installing google protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I just want to be sure: if you want to use google protocol buffers I can find a binary for the compiler, but somehow it seems that I also need to compile the remaining source files. Is this true? I have a MinGW c compiler, will this do. Does anybody have a make file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually the compiler is needed to compile the protobuf "schema" to a wrapper, that to be used in your code. So it is not an actual make/build process. Give some more details how will you use the proto files - i.e. what language is you project.

**UPDATE**: So it seems you don't have python-protobuf installed, or Python cannot find it.

Either install it using

```
apt-get install python-protobuf # for Ubuntu
yum install python-protobuf # for Fedora/Redhat
```

or

```
easy_install protobuf
```

or install it from source, as explained here:
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=235

Comment: My language is python. I will use the protobufs to wrap data into messages, serialize them, deserialize them at the other and into messges again and use the dataobject that they contain. I have made a protofile, but when I import the generated *-pb2.py file into the source file where I want to use it, I get the errormessage 'ImportError: no module named google.protobuf'. The reason I ask this question is that the readme.txt file that comes with the proto compiler states:"You will still need to download the source code package in order to obtain the Java or Python runtime libraries."

Comment: I've updated the answer - check the installation of the python-protobuf library.

Comment: easy_install works under Windows. Also install from source: "python setup.py install".

Comment: Ok, it works. I have no idea why, but here is what I did: 1. download and unpack the package to c:\protobuf-2.4.1 2. run ez_setup.py 3. run setup.py install 4. after that i tested with setup.py test and it passed. I could not run easy_install (and could not find the file on my pc). It works, but I have no idea why. Thanks everybody.

Comment: I'll vouch for a similar method: `$ sudo pip install protobuf` worked for me.